# Julia multiply each matrix along dim

Tags: julia, matrix-multiplication

I have a 3 dimensional array

```
x = rand(6,6,2^10)
```

I want to multiply each matrix along the third dimension by a vector. Is there a more clean way to do this than:

```
y = rand(6,1)
z = zeros(6,1,2^10)
for i in 1:2^10
    z[:,:,i] = x[:,:,i] * y
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are working with matrices, it may be appropriate to consider `x` as a vector of matrices instead of a 3D array. Then you could do

```
x = [rand(6,6) for _ in 1:2^10]
y = [rand(6)]
z = x .* y
```

`z` is now a vector of vectors.

And if `z` is preallocated, that would be

```
z .= x .* y
```

And, if you want it really fast, use vectors of `StaticArrays`

```
using StaticArrays

x = [@SMatrix rand(6, 6) for _ in 1:2^10]
y = [@SVector rand(6)]
z = x .* y
```

That's showing a 10x speedup on my computer, running in 12us.

Comment: It's just a dummy variable. I could have used `i` for example, but it's common to let `_` denote a throwaway variable that is not used further, and which name is unimportant.

Answer (score 7):

`mapslices(i->i*y, x, (1,2))` is maybe "cleaner" but it will be slower.

Read as: apply the function "times by y" to each slice of the first two dimensions.

```
function tst(x,y)
   z = zeros(6,1,2^10)
   for i in 1:2^10
       z[:,:,i] = x[:,:,i] * y
   end
   return z
end

tst2(x,y) = mapslices(i->i*y, x, (1,2))
```

`time tst(x,y);`
  0.002152 seconds (4.10 k allocations: 624.266 KB)

`@time tst2(x,y);`
  0.005720 seconds (13.36 k allocations: 466.969 KB)

Comment: I will agree that the solution is more "clean", but on the other hand I also find it less clear what is going on.

Comment: Maybe ... although I would agree with @DNF that if you just want to iterate over that dimension then a vector of matrices will be more readable.

Answer (score 4):

`sum(x.*y',2)` is a clean short solution.

It also has good speed and memory properties. The trick is to view matrix-vector multiplication as a linear combination of matrix's columns scaled by the vector elements. Instead of doing each linear combination for matrix x[:,:,i], we use the same scale y[i] for x[:,i,:]. In code:

```
const x = rand(6,6,2^10);
const y = rand(6,1);
function tst(x,y)
    z = zeros(6,1,2^10)
    for i in 1:2^10
        z[:,:,i] = x[:,:,i]*y
    end
    return z
end
tst2(x,y) = mapslices(i->i*y,x,(1,2))
tst3(x,y) = sum(x.*y',2)
```

Benchmarking gives:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools
julia> z = tst(x,y); z2 = tst2(x,y); z3 = tst3(x,y);
julia> @benchmark tst(x,y)
  BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
    memory estimate:  688.11 KiB
    allocs estimate:  8196
    --------------
    median time:      759.545 μs (0.00% GC)
    samples:          6068
julia> @benchmark tst2(x,y)
  BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
    memory estimate:  426.81 KiB
    allocs estimate:  10798
    --------------
    median time:      1.634 ms (0.00% GC)
    samples:          2869
julia> @benchmark tst3(x,y)
  BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
    memory estimate:  336.41 KiB
    allocs estimate:  12
    --------------
    median time:      114.060 μs (0.00% GC)
    samples:          10000
```

So `tst3` using `sum` has better performance (~7x over `tst` and ~15x over `tst2`).

Using `StaticArrays` as suggested by @DNF is also an option, and it would be nice to compare it to the solutions here.

Comment: Is there any difference between `reducedim(+, x.*y', 2)` and `sum(x.*y', 2)`?

Comment: Not really. Well, yeah, `sum` is better. I will edit to reflect this. Thanks.

Comment: BTW to really optimize, changing the ordering of indices to (6,2^10,6) and hand-coding the operation using a loop and `@inbounds` can gain another **10x**. This is to make memory layout and index calculation easier.

Comment: @DNF and **DanGetz**:  Is there an equivalent operation using the [TensorOperations](https://github.com/Jutho/TensorOperations.jl) package? If so, how does it perform?  Edit:  Perhaps `@tensor z[a,b,c] = x[a,d,c]*y[d,b]`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs The suggested expression works and even `tst4(x,y) = @tensor z[a,c] := x[a,b,c]*y[b]` works if `y` is defined as `random(6)` (i.e. Vector not Matrix). Performance is fast! About the same as the `tst3` making it a tie in terms of speed (and memory)